# can't stop ZSH autocorrect

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I've set this in my `~/.zshrc`

```
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

unsetopt correct
```

Still, ZSH is constantly trying to autocorrect.

What is the setting, configuration, etc.. that I can set to stop this super annoying behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. The option you're looking for is `unsetopt correct_all`

From `man zshoptions`:

```
       CORRECT (-0)
              Try to correct the spelling of commands.  Note that, when the HASH_LIST_ALL option is not set or when some directories in the path  are  not  readable,
              The shell variable CORRECT_IGNORE may be set to a pattern to match words that will never be offered as corrections.
       CORRECT_ALL (-O)
              Try to correct the spelling of all arguments in a line.
              The shell variable CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE may be set to a pattern to match file names that will never be offered as corrections.
```